# Store vector in cell of a numpy matrix

Tags: python, numpy

I am trying to store a vector in the cell of a numpy matrix.

```
mat=n.zeros((5,5))
vec=n.zeros(5)
mat[0][0]=vec
```

And it throws this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: setting an array element with a sequence.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change the `dtype` of `mat` to `numpy.object`. Default `dtype` of array returned by `numpy.zeros` is `float`, so you can't set an item of type `ndarray` to any of its element.

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> v = mat.astype(np.object)
>>> v[0][0] = vec
>>> v
array([[array([ 0.,  0.,  0.,  0.,  0.]), 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0],
       [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]], dtype=object)
```

Comment: v[0][0] = vec
v[0][0] and vec share the same memory space.

Comment: How do I make a copy of vec without sharing memory space.

Comment: @KAbhishek Use `v[0][0] = vec.copy()`

Comment: ok I have a huge matrix and am trying to do this:
matrix.fill(vec.copy())

The matrix is filled with objects sharing same memory. How to overcome this?

Answer (score 0):

Change the matrix `mat` to have a third dimension whose size is length of vector `vec`:

```py
mat=n.zeros((5,5,5))
```

The different pages of `mat` correspond to different components of each vector: the *i*th component of a vector is stored in the *i*th page.

Obviously, you will no longer need to initialise a vector separately nor assign the vector to a matrix cell, so you can remove the lines:

```py
vec=n.zeros(5)
mat[0][0]=vec
```

You can access each vector in the same way as before, e.g. using `mat[3,4]` to get the vector in the 3rd row and 4th column. This is because, in NumPy, `mat[3,4]` is equivalent to `mat[3,4,...]` which in this case is equivalent to `mat[3,4,:]`, which gets the elements in the 3rd row and 4th column across *all* pages, i.e. the vector in the 3rd row and 4th column (see https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/user/basics.indexing.html).